# Docker volumes on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, tomcat, centos, docker

I have run into a problem on CentOS 7 when attempting to map a volume to the host in a tomcat container. This happens with the public tomcat images as well as an image I have created (based on centos instead of debian).

instantiating a container as follows will succeed:
docker run -it -d tomcat:8

instantiating a container as follows will succeed, but with errors in the log and logs are not written to the host:
docker run -it -d -v /usr/local/tomcat:/usr/local/tomcat tomcat:8

```
[wpackard@eagle2 tomcat]$ dkr run -it -d -v 

/usr/local/tomcat:/usr/local/tomcat tomcat:8
34075701b1436f83a24212170b4d2113ae698df244c449203b1c9af9814485c9
[wpackard@eagle2 tomcat]$ dkr ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
34075701b143        tomcat:8            "catalina.sh run"   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        8080/tcp            sharp_einstein
[wpackard@eagle2 tomcat]$ dkr logs sharp_einstein
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/tomcat/logs/catalina.2015-03-31.log (Permission denied)

...

31-Mar-2015 15:32:04.088 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start Unable to create directory for deployment: /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost
31-Mar-2015 15:32:04.097 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
31-Mar-2015 15:32:04.468 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.postWorkDirectory Failed to create work directory [/usr/local/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT] for context []
31-Mar-2015 15:32:05.966 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions.<init> The scratchDir you specified: /usr/local/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT is unusable.
31-Mar-2015 15:32:06.042 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 1,929 ms
31-Mar-2015 15:32:06.043 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs
31-Mar-2015 15:32:06.093 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.postWorkDirectory Failed to create work directory [/usr/local/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/docs] for context [/docs]
31-Mar-2015 15:32:06.216 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions.<init> The scratchDir you specified: /usr/local/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/docs is unusable.
31-Mar-2015 15:32:06.219 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished in 176 ms
31-Mar-2015 15:32:06.220 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples
31-Mar-2015 15:32:06.272 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.postWorkDirectory Failed to create work directory [/usr/local/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/examples] for context [/examples]
31-Mar-2015 15:32:07.952 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions.<init> The scratchDir you specified: /usr/local/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/examples is unusable.
[wpackard@eagle2 tomcat]$
```

Exec'ing to the container and attempting to write also fails.

```
[wpackard@eagle2 tomcat]$ dkr ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
34075701b143        tomcat:8            "catalina.sh run"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        8080/tcp            sharp_einstein
[wpackard@eagle2 tomcat]$ dkr exec -it sharp_einstein /bin/bash
root@34075701b143:/usr/local/tomcat# ls -l
total 96
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 56977 Jan 23 11:59 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root  1397 Jan 23 11:59 NOTICE
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root  6779 Jan 23 11:59 RELEASE-NOTES
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root 16204 Jan 23 11:59 RUNNING.txt
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root root  4096 Mar 31 12:14 bin
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root root  4096 Jan 23 11:59 conf
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root root  4096 Mar 31 12:14 lib
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root root     6 Jan 23 11:56 logs
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root root    29 Mar 31 12:14 temp
drwxrwxr-x. 7 root root    76 Jan 23 11:57 webapps
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root root     6 Jan 23 11:56 work
root@34075701b143:/usr/local/tomcat# cd logs
root@34075701b143:/usr/local/tomcat/logs# echo "test" > test.log
bash: test.log: Permission denied
```

I have created an instance of the postgresql container on centos and that successfully maps and uses the volume, verified by creating a db, stopping the instance and then re-running the container.

```
[wpackard@eagle2 ~]$ uname --all
Linux eagle2 3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 29 18:05:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[wpackard@eagle2 ~]$
```

dkr is an alias to docker, I have created a docker group and added myself to the group to eliminate the need for sudo.

The volume mapping seems to work correctly on ubuntu. On CentOS I have tried both the package version (as below), and also updating it to 1.5.

```
[wpackard@eagle2 ~]$ dkr --version
Docker version 1.3.2, build 39fa2fa/1.3.2
[wpackard@eagle2 ~]$
```

How do I make volumes work on CentOS?

Answer (score 0):

I think your volumes *are* working :-)  You have a permission problem.  I run into this fairly often with the mapping of user id between the host and the container.  On your host, if you look at /usr/local/tomcat (ls -ld), you will see a owner, group and the permissions.  You probably have something like 0755 (read/write/exec by owner, read/exec by group, read/exec by world.  You can test this theory easily, simple remember the current settings for /usr/local/tomcat/logs, then do:

```
chmod 777 /usr/local/tomcat/logs
```

from the *docker host* (not the container).  Then run your test on the container, the Permission denied should evaporate.

This is NOT a good fix, though.  I don't know what the community says about user id mapping for docker.  One thing you could do is figure out the user and group in your host for that directory.  Then, when you create your image (or at run time) create a user with the same id and a group with the same id in the container.  Then run your tomcat service using that user in the container.

Comment: Greg, thanks - and I think you are correct in that I have a permission problem, not a volume problem. That said, the fix you suggested does not work.      
  
    `$ ll /usr/local/tomcat
    drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root      6 Apr  6 09:23 logs
    $ dkr run -it -d -v /usr/local/tomcat/logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs tomcat:8
    5661653ac2
    $ dkr logs 5661653ac2
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
    ...
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/tomcat/logs/catalina.2015-04-06.log (Permission denied)`
  
I am wondering if there is an issue with the filesytem: xfs?

Comment: I have had a lot of trouble with user id mapping and permissions between the host file systems and the container id.  I think that is what you have going on here. it is hard to read the comment output...sorry...in the container can you 'touch /usr/local/tomcat/logs/catalina.2015-04-06.log'? Does that file already exist with the wrong permission?  Or, is java creating it with the wrong permission??? (umask set wrong)???

Comment: Sorry for the garble, having a hard time formatting in the comment block.

On the host nothing exists in the logs folder, I can touch or create a file there. In the container nothing exists in that folder either, and I cannot create anything. the touch attempt returns 'Permission denied.' The permissions shown for that folder (logs) in the container are 777, owner and group are both root. Umask is 0022.

Comment: ok, so I just created a directory called /usr/local/tomcat, 777, as root. then i created a directory /usr/local/tomcat/logs, 775, as root. Then I launch container as you have listed in problem statement, but I ran bash instead of the default entrypoint.  I then cd to /usr/local/tomcat/logs and touch file, that worked fine. I am running Ubuntu 14 as my host.  So, you might be on to something with CentOS as the host having a bug?  So, I install centos 7 and do the same experiment, it works. dunno.

Comment: Went back and tried another system, replaced Ubuntu with CentOS 7, installed docker, tired tomcat. Same issue. Tired debian:wheezy and mapped a volume. Same issue. Tried postgres, it works. Strange. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Only thing I notice is that there is a user account with the same id (999) as the container's postgres user. Will try that rabbit hole and see if it helps at all. Still strange that root doesn't have access though. Thanks for you help (and patience).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to SELinux.

You must attach correct type to host directory:

```
host$ chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /usr/local/tomcat
```